# SQL Assistance - SELECT/WHERE/CASE?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am banging my head against the desk here trying to work something out in SQL, I understand the logic and I can easily complete the task in Excel however where is the fun in that :)

The database in question as a WorkOrder table and I am selecting the following columns:

```
SELECT WorkOrderNumber,
WorkOrderDescription,
WorkOrderHistoryDescription,
RaisedDateTime,
FinishedDateTime
```

What I need I am trying to do is return all work orders raised within a given month which is easy enough:

```
WHERE RaisedDateTime >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-12-01' ) and <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-12-31' )
```

The kicker is I also want those return those records that were raised prior to but were closed in the given month, I tried the following which appeared to work:

```
WHERE ( RaisedDateTime >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-12-01' ) AND RaisedDateTime <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-12-31' ) )
OR ( FinishedDateTime >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-12-01' ) AND FinishedDateTime <= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-12-31' ) AND RaisedDateTime < CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-12-01' ) )
```

However when I inserted PreventativeMaintenanceID IS NULL after the statement above I found work orders that had a value in that column, if I just have the first line of the WHERE statement everything works fine.

Any ideas/pointers of where I might be going wrong? I was looking to see if I could use a CASE statement however I just couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected results.

Comment: Show how you added `PreventativeMaintenanceID IS NULL`

Comment: My guess is you just have to group your criteria using `()` where appropriate. You have an OR in your where clause.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without knowing how exactly your full query looks but try grouping your criteria other than that line, and then add that line after the grouped criteria, like this:

```
SELECT WorkOrderNumber,
       WorkOrderDescription,
       WorkOrderHistoryDescription,
       RaisedDateTime,
       FinishedDateTime
  from tbl
 WHERE (
       (RaisedDateTime between CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-12-01') AND
       CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-12-31')) OR
       (FinishedDateTime between CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-12-01') AND
       CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-12-31') AND
       RaisedDateTime < CONVERT(DATETIME, '2014-12-01'))
       )
   and PreventativeMaintenanceID IS NULL
```

Based on your description it sounds like an order of operations issue due to the OR